# Javascript: How change function call params on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-call

I'm receiving some 'body' content from a jquery's json call, where I can get the unique javascript element returned by doing:

```
script_element = $(data.body)[1]
```

This equals to:

```
<script type=​"text/​javascript">​
    updater('foo', 'bar', {}, '0', constant='');
</script>​
```

So, `typeof script_element` returns `"object"`

And, if I run `script_element.innerText`, I can get:

```
updater('foo', 'bar', {}, '0', constant='');
```

After receiving this script, what I'm doing right now is just run an `eval` on it, but searching around I couldn't get a way to run `eval` changing function call params.

What I'm trying to do is change the `third` param of the call, in this case the `{}`, that can change depending on the return of the json call, so I can't just search for `{}`.

I could also do `script_element.text.split(',')[2]` for example, and change this text on the fly, but I was thinking there should be a better way to do this.

I don't know if javascript can recognize and treat a "future method call", but still think there should be a better way.

Any idea?

Comment: Really, there is no "more beautiful" ways different from that you know :)

Comment: @RReverser I was thinking there should be something like `new FunctionCall` (as exists `new Function`), and then a `.changeParam(2, 'new_value')`. This would be AWESOME! Or, just a better way then that `.split`

Comment: If you can change what is being returned by your server-side code, you should.  Embedding JavaScript in HTML being sent of the wire in JSON is **probably** a bit much.  Better to send over the data structures you need and then use JavaScript to build the HTML you need on the client side (and then you can make calls to your functions with the proper parameters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is shadowing the function so as to be able to alter the third argument. You ought to define that shadowing function before fetching the JSON.

```
var originalUpdater = updater; // keep old function to call

// overwrite (shadowing)
updater = function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    // change c appropriately here
    originalUpdater(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

Then you can still just `eval` it (which is not very safe, but that's not your point if I'm not mistaking), and it will call the shadow function.

---

A more generic shadowing method would be along the lines of:

```
var originalUpdater = updater; // keep old function to call

// overwrite (shadowing)
updater = function() {
    // change arguments[2] appropriately here
    originalUpdater.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7dLX/

Comment: I would have posted the same - with the caveat that I'd probably wrap the whole business in a (function(){})() wrapper so as not to expose 'originalUpdater' to the global scope.  Also, you might want to restore 'updater' after the call - but that's application specific.

Comment: I got what you mean, and maybe will do that, but I was hoping there would be a even better way. This one orders me to have a last param, so that I can pass wether or not to change it, and how to generate the new value or receive it. Anyway, thanks to answer. I'll wait more responses, and if don't get a better one, will accept yours as the better one. :)

Comment: @Gabriel L. Oliveira I think @pimvdb is right, that's really tricky but nice solution :)

Comment: @Gabriel L. Oliveira: Could you tell me what exactly do you mean with 'orders me to have a last param'?

Comment: Becase I was thinking in something generic, such that I can apply different behaviours on different parts of events. In this case, I'd apply an `if` into this wrapper function, or move the outside logic into it. Although, thanks for this answer.

Comment: @pimvdb Thank you for this one again. I'll use it as to change future behaviours along with some event binds. Thanks.

Comment: @pimvdb This is really awesome. Give more possibilities

Comment: @pimvdb Forget what I told with "order me to have a last param". Now, I'm overriding the `updater` function just when some events are thrown, and this way I can just treat the params as I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Change the server. Rather than returning

```
<script type=​"text/​javascript">​
    updater('foo', 'bar', {}, '0', constant='');
</script>​
```

Return

```
{
  "method": "updater",
  "params": [
    "foo", "bar", {}, "0", ''
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't change this, because it's an extern call to a part of the system I can't put my hands on.

Comment: @Gabriel L. Oliveira then write a proxy for the extern server which has a sensible API and returns data in a sensible format

Comment: Isn't there a way to convert that object to this JSON format?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you cannot change what is being sent over from the server, you can simply run through the `innerText` with a regular expression and pass update the HTML before you insert it.

```
var replacer = /\w+\(([^()]+)\)/gi;
script_element.innerText.replace(replacer, function(matched_text, func_params){
    var orig_func_params = func_params;
    // Make changes to func_params here.
    return matched_text.replace(orig_func_params, func_params);
});
```

This can be functionized by doing the following:

```
var replacer = /\w+\(([^()]+)\)/gi;
function replace_arg(script_element, arg_index, replacement_value) {
    script_element.innerHTML = script_element.innerHTML.replace(replacer, 
    function(matched_text, func_params){
        var orig_func_params = func_params;
        func_params = func_params.split(",");
        if (arg_index >= func_params.length) {
             throw new RangeError(arg_index + " is out of range. Total args in function:" + func_params.length);
        }
        func_params[arg_index] = JSON.stringify(replacement_value);
        return matched_text.replace(orig_func_params, func_params.join(","));
    });
return script_element;
}
```

This can be called in this way:

```
script_element = replace_arg(script_element, 3, {"new":"arg"});
```

Comment: This looks like a good way, but even better if I could put the number of the param (in this case, third one).

Comment: Thank you. I'll also re-use your code too, because it's also AWESOME.

Comment: This will fit me better, as I'm able to change param wherever 'javascript' element-tag I take. Thank you @Sean

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are doing, but in general if you don't want to rely on the order of parameters make the function take one parameter that is an object whose properties are the parameters:

```
function add(params) {
    var a = params.hasOwnProperty("paramA") ? params.paramA : 0;
    var b = params.hasOwnProperty("paramB") ? params.paramB : 0;
    return a + b;
}

add({paramA: 1, paramB: 2});
```

In this case you should use hasOwnProperty to check if the function was passed the parameter you are looking for before trying to access it.

Comment: Yeah, but sorry. I'm not trying to change the `updater` function, just params before calling it.